# Flutter run xcode build fails but building directly with xcode succeeded

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm new to iOS development and I ran into this problem at the very beginning:
When I tried to flutter run my hello world app I got xcodebuild failed (I took only the last lines since it's too long):

```
    81 errors generated.
    <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/mehec/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cssmbpuzzkyjvpfghedbpvdhbbmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2PXLF604USZTM-clang_KLU4EDN5EN1U.pch' for bridging header '/Users/mehec/Desktop/bgp/learn_flutter_0_test/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
    <unknown>:0: error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

I then tried to build and run in xcode and everything's fine.

I have tried flutter clean and flutter upgrade even creating a new project but no effect

I'm using macOS 10.14.6, IntelliJ Idea 2020.1, Flutter 1.17.5 and 1.19.0, Xcode  11.3.1

the code in main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Center(
    child: Text(
      "hello world",
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    ),
  ));
}
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G5033, locale en-US)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
The build from Xcode.app was successful, but the build from the command line or Android Studio failed.

Finally, I reinstalled rbenv, and the problem went away.

In other Github comments, some people solved the problem with `conda deactivate`, so I think the problem is caused by a bug in the development environment that Xcode.app does not refer to, such as ruby or python environment.